# Android how to display data of only a particular user in list using ParseQueryAdapter

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a parseobject called trips. I would like to display the data of the trips of a particular user who is signed in only at any point of time in a fragment rather than the entire table of trips. I am using the following code for this ;

```
public class TripListAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<Trips> {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyy");
    public TripListAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<Trips>() {
            public ParseQuery<Trips> create() {
                // Here we can configure a ParseQuery to display
                // only top-rated meals.
                ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Trips");
                query.whereEqualTo("user", currentUser);
                //query.whereContainedIn("rating", Arrays.asList("5", "4"));
                query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
                return query;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View getItemView(Trips trips, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (v == null) {
            v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.item_trip_list, null);
        }

        super.getItemView(trips, v, parent);

        //ParseImageView mealImage = (ParseImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        //ParseFile photoFile = meal.getParseFile("photo");
        //if (photoFile != null) {
            //mealImage.setParseFile(photoFile);
            //mealImage.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                //@Override
                //public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                    // nothing to do
            //  }
            //});
        //}

        TextView destinationTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.trip_destination);
        destinationTextView.setText(trips.getDestination());
        TextView durationTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.trip_duration);
        durationTextView.setText(formatter.format(trips.getStartDate())+" - "+formatter.format(trips.getEndDate()));
        return v;
    }
```

But when i run the app, i am able to see the data created by all the users. How do i fix this ?
Thanks

Comment: What happens if you run this query outside of a QTVA?  Is "user" a column of type Pointer<_User> in the data browser?

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something very similar, and it's working. The only difference I can see is in this line

```
ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Trips");
```

Instead of that I did the equivalent of

```
ParseQuery<Trips> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Trips.class);
query.include("user"); // Don't think this will matter
```

Let me know if this works.